# Finding the the difference in day from previous record and partitioning by category

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, partitioning

I have the following table:

```
+----------+------------+----------------+
| Customer |    Date    | DesiredDayDiff |
+----------+------------+----------------+
| aaa      | 12/09/2018 |              0 |
| aaa      | 18/09/2018 |              6 |
| aaa      | 25/09/2018 |             13 |
| aaa      | 27/09/2018 |             15 |
| aaa      | 28/09/2018 |             16 |
| bbb      | 07/09/2018 |              0 |
| bbb      | 11/09/2018 |              4 |
| bbb      | 11/09/2018 |              4 |
+----------+------------+----------------+
```

I need to be able to calculate the difference of day from previous record, for that particular customer.

I believe there is added functionality in SQL server 2012+ that allows some sort of window functioning?? If this can be done using a window function, this would be a bonus as it hopefully, allows my query to be a lot more tidy.

I couldn't find a similar thread where the solution partitions by another category (in this instance above, it's the customer)

Comment: Eh? The row for the 25th is 7 days after the *previous* row for the same customer. Your desired column appears to be showing the difference from the *first* row. Which are you after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow your narrative and diff from the previous row, [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) works for that:

```
declare @t table (Customer char(3), Date date, DesiredDayDiff int)
insert into @t(Customer,Date,DesiredDayDiff) values
('aaa','20180912',0),
('aaa','20180918',6),
('aaa','20180925',13),
('aaa','20180927',15),
('aaa','20180928',16),
('bbb','20180907',0),
('bbb','20180911',4),
('bbb','20180911',4)

select
    *,
    COALESCE(DATEDIFF(day,LAG(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER By Date),Date),0)
from
    @t
```

Results:

```
Customer Date       DesiredDayDiff 
-------- ---------- -------------- -----------
aaa      2018-09-12 0              0
aaa      2018-09-18 6              6
aaa      2018-09-25 13             7
aaa      2018-09-27 55             2
aaa      2018-09-28 66             1
bbb      2018-09-07 0              0
bbb      2018-09-11 4              4
bbb      2018-09-11 4              0
```

To match your "desired" column, I have to use [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead.

Comment: Excellent, it was the FIRST_VALUE version that I needed (as per my table), sorry for causing confusion.